# Populating a CardView with an ArrayList of Objects android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I have some code which adds objects to an `arrayList` and displays them in a `ListView` - this works perfectly

I then send the Array through an intent - it is received perfectly

**Now...**

I want to use this array to populate a *Card* `(android.support.v7.widget.CardView)` I am using a `RecyclerView` to display the cards, but my only issue is, the `RecyclerView` adapter iterates through the given array and adds a card per item in the array using the **position**.

I want to be able to use the objects in the Array to populate a single card. Please tell me if you need me to explain this better, it's quite a tricky one to put into words!

**Here is some code:**

This is the code that adds the items to a `listView` and an array:

```
public class AddExerciseView extends ActionBarActivity {

    TrackDatabaseAdapter mTrackDatabaseAdapter;

    TextView workoutName;
    EditText weight, reps;
    double weightCount;
    int repsCount;
    ListView list;
    Button plus, plus2, minus, minus2, update;
    String name;
    int type, category, count;
    Exercise ex;
    ArrayList<Set> array;
    private AddExerciseAdapter mAddExerciseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_workout_view);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            name = extras.getString("ExerciseName");
            type = extras.getInt("ExerciseType");
            category = extras.getInt("ExerciseCategory");
        }
        mTrackDatabaseAdapter = new TrackDatabaseAdapter(this);

        ActionBar actionBar = AddExerciseView.this.getSupportActionBar();

        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setTitle(name);
        }

        ex = new Exercise(name, type, category);
        Log.v("Exercise Recieved", ex.toString());
        workoutName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textWeight);
        reps = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textRep);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rowReps);
        plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
        minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
        plus2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus2);
        minus2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus2);
        update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);

        weightCount = 0;
        repsCount = 0;
        count = 1;

        array = new ArrayList<>();

        plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!weight.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    weightCount = Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());
                    weightCount = weightCount + 2.5;
                    weight.setText(String.valueOf(weightCount));
                } else {
                    weight.setText(String.valueOf(2.5));
                }
            }
        });

        minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (weightCount <= 0.0 || weight.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    weight.setText(String.valueOf(0.0));
                } else {
                    weightCount = Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());
                    weightCount = weightCount - 2.5;
                    weight.setText(String.valueOf(weightCount));
                }
            }
        });

        plus2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!reps.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    repsCount = Integer.parseInt(reps.getText().toString());
                    repsCount = repsCount + 1;
                    reps.setText(String.valueOf(repsCount));
                } else {
                    reps.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                }
            }
        });

        minus2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (repsCount <= 0 || reps.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    reps.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                } else {
                    repsCount = Integer.parseInt(reps.getText().toString());
                    repsCount = repsCount - 1;
                    reps.setText(String.valueOf(repsCount));
                }
            }
        });

        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (weight.getText().toString().equals("") || weight.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(0.0))) {
                    weight.setText(String.valueOf(0.0));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You need to enter a weight!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (reps.getText().toString().equals("") || reps.getText().toString().equals(String.valueOf(0))) {
                    reps.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You need to have at least 1 rep!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    double temp2 = Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());
                    int temp3 = Integer.parseInt(reps.getText().toString());
                    Set s = new Set(name, temp2, temp3);
                    array.add(s);
                    mAddExerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mTrackDatabaseAdapter.insertEntry(name, temp2, temp3);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        });

        mAddExerciseAdapter = new AddExerciseAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row2, array);
        list.setAdapter(mAddExerciseAdapter);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add_exercise, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_done) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AddExerciseView.this, MainMenuView2.class);
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("array", array);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

This is the code that uses the adapter, so it receivesthe array from the other activity and gives it to the adapter:

```
public class MainMenuView2 extends ActionBarActivity {

    //List<Exercise> list = new ArrayList<>();
    TrackDatabaseAdapter mTrackDatabaseAdapter;
    List<Set> set = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Set> test = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("array") != null) {
            set = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("array");
            for (Set s : set) {
                Log.d("Parcelable Array", s.toString());
            }
        }
        mTrackDatabaseAdapter = new TrackDatabaseAdapter(this);
        if (mTrackDatabaseAdapter.getAllCategories().size() == 0) {
            test = mTrackDatabaseAdapter.getAllCategories();
        }
        Log.v("test array", test.toString());
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu2);

        ActionBar actionBar = MainMenuView2.this.getSupportActionBar();

        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setTitle("ProjectME");
        }

        RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
        recList.setHasFixedSize(false);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recList.setLayoutManager(llm);
        CardAdapter ca = new CardAdapter(set);
        recList.setAdapter(ca);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_add) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Add has been clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent create = new Intent(MainMenuView2.this, CategoryListView.class);
            startActivity(create);
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_copy) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copy has been clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_cal) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Calendar has been clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent create = new Intent(MainMenuView2.this, CalendarView.class);
            startActivity(create);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And this is the adapter,right now it is wrong and throwing me an array out of bounds error,I already know why,but thought I would share my attempt,the one before just created new cards each time and changed only 1 line:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {

    private List<Set> contactList;

    public CardAdapter(List<Set> contactList) {
        this.contactList = contactList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, int i) {

        int x = contactList.size();
        Log.v("array size", x + "");

        if (contactList.get(i) != null) {
            contactViewHolder.vName.setText(contactList.get(i).getName());
            contactViewHolder.vReps.setText(contactList.get(i).getReps() + "");
            contactViewHolder.vWeight.setText(contactList.get(i).getWeight() + "");
        }
        if (contactList.get(i + 1) != null) {
            contactViewHolder.vName.setText(contactList.get(i).getName());
            contactViewHolder.vReps1.setText(contactList.get(i + 1).getReps() + "");
            contactViewHolder.vWeight1.setText(contactList.get(i + 1).getWeight() + "");
        }
        if (contactList.get(i + 2) != null) {
            contactViewHolder.vName.setText(contactList.get(i + 2).getName());
            contactViewHolder.vReps2.setText(contactList.get(i + 2).getReps() + "");
            contactViewHolder.vWeight2.setText(contactList.get(i + 2).getWeight() + "");

        }
        if (contactList.get(i + 3) != null) {
            contactViewHolder.vName.setText(contactList.get(i + 3).getName());
            contactViewHolder.vReps3.setText(contactList.get(i + 3).getReps() + "");
            contactViewHolder.vWeight3.setText(contactList.get(i + 3).getWeight() + "");

        }
        if (contactList.get(i + 4) != null) {
            contactViewHolder.vName.setText(contactList.get(i + 4).getName());
            contactViewHolder.vReps4.setText(contactList.get(i + 4).getReps() + "");
            contactViewHolder.vWeight4.setText(contactList.get(i + 4).getWeight() + "");

        }
        if (contactList.size() > 4) {
            contactViewHolder.vShowMore.setText("Show " + (contactList.size() - 5) + " more");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.card_view, viewGroup, false);

        ContactViewHolder cvh = new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
        return cvh;
    }

    public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView vName;
        protected TextView vWeight;
        protected TextView vReps;
        protected TextView vWeight1;
        protected TextView vReps1;
        protected TextView vWeight2;
        protected TextView vReps2;
        protected TextView vWeight3;
        protected TextView vReps3;
        protected TextView vWeight4;
        protected TextView vReps4;
        protected TextView vShowMore;

        public ContactViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            vName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            vWeight = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            vReps = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView9);

            vWeight1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
            vReps1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView13);

            vWeight2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView15);
            vReps2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView17);

            vWeight3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView19);
            vReps3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView21);

            vWeight4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView23);
            vReps4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView25);

            vShowMore = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView32);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that this isn't actually possible, well it might be, but it would be very very very hard. 
I just created a class where it stores the List and the name of the exercise, and then inside the adapter I just use

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, int i) {
    Card card = cards.get(i);
    List<Set> sets = card.getSet();
    int x = sets.size();
    int count = 0;

    for(Set set : sets) {
        if(count == 0) {
            contactViewHolder.vName.setText(set.getName());
            contactViewHolder.vReps.setText(set.getReps() + "");
            contactViewHolder.vWeight.setText(set.getWeight() + "");
        } if(count == 1) {
            contactViewHolder.vReps1.setText(set.getReps() + "");
            contactViewHolder.vWeight1.setText(set.getWeight() + "");
        } if(count == 2) {
            contactViewHolder.vReps2.setText(set.getReps() + "");
            contactViewHolder.vWeight2.setText(set.getWeight() + "");
        } if(count == 3) {
            contactViewHolder.vReps3.setText(set.getReps() + "");
            contactViewHolder.vWeight3.setText(set.getWeight() + "");
        } if(count == 4) {
            contactViewHolder.vReps4.setText(set.getReps() + "");
            contactViewHolder.vWeight4.setText(set.getWeight() + "");
        } if(x > 4) {
            contactViewHolder.vShowMore.setText((x - 5) + " More");
        }
        count++;
    }


}
```

It now shows what I need and it is simpler to read too.